# Automatic mediawiki article generation with a script?

Tags: rss, mediawiki

In mediawiki, the user can create a new article by manual create a page. He press the “new”-button, put the text into the editor and safes the edit. The article is stored in the normal SQL database. I would like to do something which is more advanced. The page should be created with a script. That means, the user with admin rights starts the script, and 100 articles are created in batch mode. Each article is filled with the same standard template.

The reason why i'd like to do so is because to solve the content aggregation problem. To be more specific, the idea is to use the planet 2.0 rss reader to combine 100 existing streams from blogs but not generating a HTML page with the combined RSS stream but use the feed for generating mediawiki articles. That means, entry1 in the planet feed is converted into article1 in the mediawiki system, entry2 into the article2 and so on.

I know, the problem of using planet software for doing the overall task is a second question so I'm happy if someone can explain only how to create a mediawiki article with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) is a common tool for such tasks that does not require extending MediaWiki.

If you do want to extend MediaWiki, you can do something along the lines of

```
$user = User::newSytsemUser( 'Some username' );
$title = Title::newFromText( 'Some article title' );
$page = WikiPage::factory( $title );
$content = new WikitextContent( 'some article text' );
$status = $page->doEditContent( $content, 'some edit summary', 0, false, $user );
```

See the [special page manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Special_pages) on how to embed the code into MediaWiki.